# Drawing histogram with too many variables using barchart in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, bar-chart

I'm simply trying to draw a histogram for some x I calculate but before I draw the histogram I have to sort them. The problem is x is too long(Like 2 million variables). Is there any method to reduce the time of drawing histogram. I think drawing too many bars takes so much time so how can I simply reduce the number of them without losing the shape?

```
x = someFunctionCreatingAListOfVariables()
x.sort(reverse = True)
plt.bar(left = np.arange(len(x)), height = x, color='b')
```

Comment: What your code does doesn't look like a histogram.  You're drawing a separate bar for every data point.  A histogram will group the points into "bins" and draw only one bar per bin.

Comment: Any reason why you're not using `plt.hist`?